# Mimedefang to log spamassassin scores to mail log

Tags: sendmail, spamassassin

I use mimedefang with spamassassin and sendmail I can see the scores and tests in to the mail log if the mail does not get rejected as spam by adding it to the header of the mail.

I would like to see the same info in the mail log when a mail is rejected. It will have to log it to the mail log as putting it in the headers wont work for rejected mail. Below is a part of the log for mail that does not get rejected, I would like the same info in the mail log.

```
v9D6s0vS026180: Milter add: header: X-Spam-Status: No, hits=-0.325 required=5 HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS,HTML_FONT_LOW_CONTRAST,HTML_MESSAGE,RP_MATCHES_RCVD,T_DKIM_INVALID
```

Here is my mimedefang config

I have this enabled

```
 md_graphdefang_log_enable('mail', 1);
```

and here is my part that deals with the reject

```
    # Spam checks if SpamAssassin is installed

if ($Features{"SpamAssassin"}) {
    if (-s "./INPUTMSG" < 100*1024) {
        # Only scan messages smaller than 100kB.  Larger messages
        # are extremely unlikely to be spam, and SpamAssassin is
        # dreadfully slow on very large messages.
        my($hits, $req, $names, $report) = spam_assassin_check();
        my($score);
        if ($hits < 40) {
            $score = "*" x int($hits);
        } else {
            $score = "*" x 40;
        }
        # We add a header which looks like this:
        # X-Spam-Score: 6.8 (******) NAME_OF_TEST,NAME_OF_TEST
        # The number of asterisks in parens is the integer part
        # of the spam score clamped to a maximum of 40.
        # MUA filters can easily be written to trigger on a
        # minimum number of asterisks...
        if ($hits >= $req) {
            return action_bounce("REJECT SPAMD This message is deemed to be SPAM");
            md_graphdefang_log('spam', $hits, $names, $RelayAddr);

     } else {
            # Delete any existing X-Spam-Score header?
            #action_delete_header("X-Spam-Score");
            action_add_header("X-Spam-Status", "No, hits=$hits required=$req $names");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `md_graphdefang_log` **before** you exit `filter_end` subroutine via `return`.

BTW `md_graphdefang_log` takes only three (3) parameters.